# Shuttle like app but for running any command

Tags: menu-bar

I was really impressed with Shuttle app for mac:
http://fitztrev.github.io/shuttle/

I want similar app which can manage the frequently accessed folders/files and commands (like start/stop/restart of apache, mysql server etc.)

Do such app exists for Mac which uses similar json like configuration?
Please share.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with Shuttle you can run any terminal command. Just write the desired command instead of the ssh command.